# Can I use IP addresses not Domain Names in OpenAM?

Tags: openam

I'm not sure that this is a proper question. (I'm the novice about stackoverflow strategies)

I'm trying to configure SSO systems using OpenAM.
 OpenAM... is not a light solution, but I did get my solution for my boss' request.
 We have several Web Applications. (App1, App2, App3, ...)
 I simulated the combination [OpenAM + App1].
 That's OK~ (though much time and so many trials were needed.)
 I used domain names following the guide.
 [openam.example.com + www.app1.com]

But, in our real circumstances, We should use the IP addresses.
 (for example, OpenAM : 1.1.1.1, App1 : 2.2.2.2)
 Guide seems to say "it's not possible"...
 and I failed about that trial.
 when I used 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' (for simple simulations)
 App1(tomcat) failed to start.
 Agent's logs were like this...

```
ERROR: Failed to obtain auth service url from server: null://null:null
ERROR: AdminTokenAction: FATAL ERROR: Cannot obtain Application SSO token.
Check AMConfig.properties for the following properties
    com.sun.identity.agents.app.username
    com.iplanet.am.service.password
```

Is there a way to user IP addresses for OpenAM SSO?
 If possible, my situation is just due to my mistake?

Thank you in advance... (and sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 2):

In short - no, it is not possible.  You must use DNS names (and do not use localhost - this is asking for trouble).  OpenAM uses cookies for SSO, and cookies require DNS names.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Strange.
We should change our situation or solution.